# How to update a database programmatically, so that the updated one is included when publishing?

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I'm copying and updating data from another database to mine (programmatically), this works fine when debugging. It also remembers it between debugging sessions. However, when I publish the program, the original database is empty.

How do I make sure the updated one is included?
This is an SQLCE database by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are debugging the compiler will copy your SqlCe database to the bin\debug folder and that's the one you will be using when your program is running.

So when you copy data while debugging it will not end up in the database that is a part of your project but in the one in the debug folder!

Using the following [tool](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/) could help. This will allow you to script the data that's in your database to a sql script so you can run it in your publish environment.